# Unable To Load Regulatory Database

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

I am trying to bring up a 4.19 (4.19.16) kernel on my board using the Atmel AT91SAM9G45 SOC.  I included the CRDA support in the kernel configuration, but the kernel reports that it is unable to load the regulatory.db file during boot.

```
cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=2514, bcdDevice= 0.00
usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
hub 1-2:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-2:1.0: 4 ports detected
cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
Waiting 1 sec before mounting root device...
usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using atmel-ehci
usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9378, bcdDevice= 3.00
usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-1.2: Product: USBWLAN
usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Qualcomm Atheros
usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 12345678
usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using atmel-ehci
usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0d8c, idProduct=0008, bcdDevice= 1.00
usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-1.4: Product: C-Media USB Audio Device   
EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
Freeing unused kernel memory: 1024K
Run /sbin/init as init process
INIT: version 2.86 booting
Please wait: booting...
```

I have placed the `regulatory.db` and `regulatory.db.p7s` files in the `/lib/firmware` directory, but it still fails.  It looks to me like the kernel is attempting to load the `regulatory.db` file before it mounts the file system on which it resides.

How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 3):

I think I have resolved this issue by changing the kernel configuration to build the cfg80211 code as a module (CONFIG_CFG80211=m) instead of a built-in (CONFIG_CFG80211=y).  This forces the code that loads the regulatory database file as firmware to run after the root file system is mounted.

Comment: Many thanks, this solved the issue for me as well. I wonder whether there is a way to force the builtin driver loading the database after the rootfs has been mounted, or retrying it.